# Software center install name to package installed without diffing dpkg output

Tags: apt, software-center

Something I ran across in the wee hours of the morning this morning was that the software center samba package differs from the samba apt-get package.  How do you in a direct way (as in from software center or some other direct method...not pre-install post-install package list diff-ing) determine what package/pseudo-package a software center line item pulls in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name for a given application is listed by *Version* on its details page.

[image: Image highlighting version information]

Answer (score 2):

That was a little bit difficult to understand. Yes, Samba in the Software Center is not the same as the package called "samba".

If you click "More information", you can see the version information. In Precise, it says: «system-config-samba 1.2.63-0ubuntu5».